# Open Latest File

Tags: batch-file, autodesk-navisworks

I'm having a little trouble and hope someone here can help me out.

The code below copies the latest version of a file to my target directory. I'm wanting to also open the latest file that was copied into my target directory. 
The filename isnt constant, so it needs to be able to find the most recent file to open.

```
@echo off
set source="N:\Project\c1662\shareddata\3d-Model-Index"
set target="C:\NWD"

ECHO Copying files..........please weait

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.nwd /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY 
%source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END
:END

start "" "C:\Users\nortonjl\Desktop\Navisworks Simulate 2015.lnk" 
???

:End
```

Comment: Are you wanting to open the file you've just copied to the target directory? or the latest file in the target directory after the latest file from the source directory has been copied?

Comment: The latest file in the target directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to open the latest file found from the `for` loop. Here is a way you can do this:

```bat
@echo off
set "source=N:\Project\c1662\shareddata\3d-Model-Index"
set "target=C:\NWD"

echo Copying files..........please weait

for /f "delims=" %%I IN ('dir %source%\*.nwd /A:-D /O:-D /B') do (
     copy "%%~fI" %target%
     set "latest_file=%%~nxI"
     echo %%I
)
goto END

:END
start "" "C:\Users\nortonjl\Desktop\Navisworks Simulate 2015.lnk" 
start "" "%target%\%latest_file%"
```

Comment: Thank you. The only issue now is its not copying the file.